# How can I set a delay of 5 seconds when the timer hits 00:00?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, countdowntimer

I'm setting up a countdown timer to an application, and when this countdown hits the mark of 00:00 I want to have 5 seconds of delay before it restarts counting down again. How can i use setTimeout() to make it?

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
            minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
            seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

            minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
            seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

           display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

            if (--timer < 0) {
                timer = duration;
            }
    }, 1000);
    duration = timer;
}
```

Comment: `var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;` makes no sense

Comment: possible duplicate :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29455528/how-to-delay-setinterval-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interval will continue ticking until you clear it, so what you need to do is when the timer hits zero, clear the interval and then set a timeout that will restart the interval. (In order to clear an interval, you need to store its returned handle in a variable first.) A bit of recursion can help here:

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
  var timerInterval = setInterval(function () {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
        window.clearInterval(timerInterval);
        window.setTimeout(() => startTimer(duration, display), 5000);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just wrap the line `timer = duration;` in a function and pass it to `setTimeout`. Only display the updated time if the `timer >= 0` otherwise it will display -ive numbers.

```js
const display = document.querySelector('#display')

function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
            if(timer >= 0){
            minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
            seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

            minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
            seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

           display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
           }

            if (--timer < 0) {
                
                setTimeout(()=>timer = duration,5000)
            }
    }, 1000);
    duration = timer;
}

startTimer(10,display)
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. You can achieve your goal by adding a second timer in your code like this:

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
            minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
            seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

            minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
            seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

           display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

            if (--timer < 0) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    timer = duration;
                },5000); // 5 seconds delay
            }
    }, 1000);
    duration = timer;
}
```

Comment: The issue with this is that the interval will still continue every second, meaning it'll go down to -5 seconds before resetting.

Comment: You are right @IceMetalPunk, but as far I can see in Maheer Ali answer's snippet using ES6 doesn't give any issues with it, does letting the interval go to -5 give a bad performance result? My curiosity just came out..

Comment: It wouldn't be a performance issue, but I would assume that displaying negative seconds on a timer would be undesired behavior.

Comment: I got your point now, well then, I only forgot to add a conditional statement to prevent the "clock display" when the timer is less than 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution **not** using `setTimeout` because it is not necessary. It just counts down to -5 (without updating the display) and then starts over.

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
            if (timer >= 0) {
                minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
                seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

                minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

                display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
            }
            
            --timer;
            
            if (timer <= -5) {
                timer = duration;
            }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  startTimer(10, document.getElementById('display'));
};
```

```html
<span id="display"></span>
```